# Pip error: Unable to create process using <file path>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, updates, anaconda3

I installed version 20.0.2 for pip last month and it worked fine when I was downloading some packages. However, tried using it again recently and it somehow gave me this new error. I've tried fixing the path variables under Environment Variables to the folder containing the earlier version (pip-18.1) and this latest version and both did not work either. The files is in my Anaconda3 folder.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

My OS is Windows 10 64 bit, and the Python verion I'm using is:

```
C:\Users\user>python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
```

When I enter pip in the command line this is the output:

```
C:\Users\user>pip
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\pkgs\pip-20.0.2-py37_1\python.exe C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\pkgs\pip-20.0.2-py37_1\Scripts\pip-script.py
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about your environment? OS, python version. A dump of env variables would help too. The output of pip would be good too,

Comment: did you try this: python -m pip

Comment: Yes I did, and this came out C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe: No module named pip @Joshua